# Build registry with BOOST::ptree

Tags: c++, boost

I need to build a registry like structure using BOOST::ptree. The point is that I am totally confused with the API! Other issue is that I got to store something like key-value pairs in each entry. And also is it possible to store multiple values in the same path? For instance I have node "root" and I would like to store there ("first" - "type") and ("second" - "type").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here is the solution. First you got to define your own ptree. This can be done as follows:

```
typedef boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::string, data_struct> owntree;
```

Here data_struct is your own data structure, where I, for instance, store 2 string values. The only point is that you have to write *swap* method for your structure. After that you can just call *put* method of the your owntree.